# How to create test database with Flask-Testing

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-testing

I want to set up test database for Flask-Testing class, so tests do not affect my main database. I need test database being created each time I run my unittests testcase
 How can I do this?

I use `Flask-Testing, Flask-SQLAlchemy, psycopg2`

Privilegies to create database properly granted. So now I just have to figure out how perform this.

Please advice how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different setting for production and testing purpose.

How to create flask app this way - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/#app-factories

## UPD

Create base_setting.py for base settings, production_setting.py and testing_setting.py with diffrerent db settings  and create app from one of them. - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#configuring-from-files

for example:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('base')
app.config.from_envvar('YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS')
```

Don't forget to set YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS env

Comment: Can you please post more detailed answer so I could accept it.